# Select only column name from an sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

As an example I have this query here

```
SELECT DISTINCT convert(varchar(10), PickupDate ,105) AS [Pickup dates]
FROM info.dbo.A_Query_Detail AS D
INNER JOIN info.dbo.A_Query_Header AS ACQ on ACQ.ID = D.Header_ID
WHERE D.HeaderID = @HeaderID 
AND ACQ.PriceType = 'Pickup'
GROUP BY 
Adrid, convert(varchar(10), PickupDate ,105)
```

What I want to get here is only the column name without it conflicts with the above query.
So my result would be something like: "Column_Date" or Pickup dates as stated above. 
I have red something about **sys.tables** but I can't seem to make it work with the above code.

Comment: I don't really get your question, you'll have one column, called `[Pickup dates]` and it will be `VarChar(10)`.

Comment: I just want the column name without the dataset

Comment: This is not volatile data, its predictable unless you use `*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a list of columns, sometimes I use a temporary view:

```
create view _MyView as <your query here>
```

Then you can do:

```
select *
from information_schema.columns
where table_name = '_MyView'
```

You can get the column names and types by doing this.

Then you can do:

```
drop view _MyView
```

(And, of course, the view name should not conflict with anything else.)

Comment: Thank you gordon I will try this and get back to you!

Comment: @MishMish, if you have to specify `<your query here>`, why not do my answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/26909275/659190

Comment: @Jodrell your answer is also good but have not tried it, actually the whole solution need to be changed anyways, It's more advanced then I thought I might upload a new question for help later. It's a  bit complicated :-)

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
SELECT 'Pickup dates' AS [ColumnName];
```

---

this is like [@Gordon Linoff's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26908955/659190) but doesn't carry the overhead of creating a view.